# Using itunes com api with Visual basic

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, itunes-sdk

i've a problem with visual basic(from visual studio 2010)
I can't find itunes com dll when i'm adding reference.
It only shows ItunesAdmin,ITdetector and Itunesoutlookaddin ....what can i do to resolve that problem? i'm using itunes 10.6.1.7.
thank you

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1829?viewlocale=en_US

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and used [iTunes COM Fix](http://www.binaryfortress.com/itunes-com-fix/) to solve it, and it worked fine.